# jQuery How to filter two dates and time from dictionary, and group at new array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I work with a dictionary array, and here I store a time stamp.

So I have a table for which I need to store data by time.

I want to filter data by time stamp and date.

```js
// Dictionary array:
var array = [
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 05:46:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 05:21:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 06:31:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 06:46:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 07:34:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 07:55:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 08:46:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 09:16:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 09:46:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 10:36:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 11:47:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 11:55:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 12:37:33" }
    ];
// And I have time periods, for ex:
var time = ["05:45 - 06:00", "06:00 - 07:00",
     "07:00 - 08:00", "08:00 - 09:00", "09:00 - 10:00",
     "10:00 - 11:00", "11:00 - 12:00", "12:00 - 13:00",
     "13:00 - 14:00",];

//I try to use this method:
const groups = array.reduce((groups, item) => {
        const date = item.dateTime.split('T')[0];
        if (!groups[date]) {
            groups[date] = [];
        }
        groups[date].push(item);
        return groups;
    }, {});
    
    const groupArrays = Object.keys(groups).map((date) => {
        return {
            date,
            games: groups[date]
        };
    });
    
console.log(groupArrays);
```

But it's not working at proper way, so I need to compare data which I have at **array**, with **time Schedule**.

So, in the end, I want to receive grouped date by hours.

In the end I want to receive:

```
 var result  = [
    { time: "05:45 - 06:00", groupedData:[
             { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 05:46:33" },
             { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 05:21:33" }
    ]
    time: "06:00 - 07:00", groupedData:[
             { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 06:31:33" },
            { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 06:46:33" }
    ]
    ];
```

I am really stuck, and I'm tired of looking for a solution.

Comment: I think this is just a javascript question. Drop the jQuery tag?

Comment: @Dr.KevinWang because here maybe is possible to use jQury

Comment: Consider running two loops: the outside one iterate on your time ranges (I would actually write each item / range on your "time table" as two time objects to facilitate comparison) and the inner one on your array that contains data. Then compare the datetime timestamp with the iterated range. Finally, you can append to your result object by key.

Comment: BTW time periods are overlapping `["05:45 - 06:00", "06:00...`. it should be like `["05:45 - 06:00", "06:01...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work around the date format in order to compara dates, my solution includes only the hours, you might need to include the minutes comparison inside the filter function in order to obtain accurate results.

Explanation:

1. First I formatted the date in order to read it and compare.
2. Use the reduce function to obtain the grouped data.
3. Include a filter function so we can obtain items that match the current value inside
   the reduce function and push the items inside the result.
4. Output the result

Hope this helps.

```js
var array = [
    { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 05:46:33" },
    { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 05:21:33" },
    { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 06:31:33" },
    { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 06:46:33" },
    { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 07:34:33" },
    { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 07:55:33" },
    { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 08:46:33" },
    { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 09:16:33" },
    { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 09:46:33" },
    { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 10:36:33" },
    { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 11:47:33" },
    { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 11:55:33" },
    { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 12:37:33" }
];

var time = ["05:45 - 06:00", "06:00 - 07:00", "07:00 - 08:00", "08:00 - 09:00", "09:00 - 10:00", "10:00 - 11:00", "11:00 - 12:00", "12:00 - 13:00", "13:00 - 14:00",];
var formatedTime = time.map(function(val) {
    return val.split(" - ");
});

var grouped = formatedTime.reduce((groups, currentValue, cI) => {
    let min = parseInt(currentValue[0].substring(0,2));
    let max = parseInt(currentValue[1].substring(0,2));
    let filtered = array.filter(val => {
        let validDate = val.dateTime.replace(/\//g,'-').replace(' ','T').replace('19','2019');
        let date = new Date(validDate).getHours();
        let result = false;
        if(date >= min && date < max) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
    

    let date = currentValue[0] + " - " + currentValue[1];
    groups.push({
        time: date,
        groupedData: filtered
    });
    return groups;

}, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, This covers your requirment. But It will add an extra property "seconds" to each object in your "array". You could remove this at the end if you would like to.

```
    var array = [
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 05:46:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 05:21:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 06:31:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 06:46:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 07:34:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 07:55:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 08:46:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 09:16:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 09:46:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 10:36:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 11:47:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 11:55:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 12:37:33" }
    ];


    array.forEach(obj => obj["seconds"] = getSeconds(obj.dateTime));

    var time = ["05:45 - 06:00", "06:00 - 07:00", "07:00 - 08:00", "08:00 - 09:00", "09:00 - 10:00", "10:00 - 11:00", "11:00 - 12:00", "12:00 - 13:00", "13:00 - 14:00"];

    var result = [];

    for (var k=0; k<time.length; k++){  
      var range = time[k]; //"05:45 - 06:00";
      range = range.split("-");
      var hrs_mins = range.map(x => x.trim());

      var lowerLimit = hrs_mins[0].split(":");
      lowerLimit = lowerLimit[0] * (60 * 60) + lowerLimit[1] * 60;
      console.log(lowerLimit);

      var upperLimit = hrs_mins[1].split(":");
      upperLimit = upperLimit[0] * (60 * 60) + upperLimit[1] * 60;
      console.log(upperLimit);

      for (var l=0; l< array.length; l++) {
        if( array[l].seconds >= lowerLimit && array[l].seconds < upperLimit) {
           var object = {};
           object["time"] = time[k];
           object["groupedData"] = array[l];
           result.push(object);
        }
      }
    }

    function getSeconds(date) {
      //date - "19/05/23 06:31:33";
      time = date.split(" ")[1].split(":");
      return (+time[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+time[1]) * 60 + (+time[2]);
    }
```