# JS Data filter and group not correct

Tags: javascript

I work with dictionary array, and I wanna group data by time period, I have a solution how to do it.

But now I found issues, for last hours data is not appear at the grouped array.

Code:

```js
    // Dictionary array:
var array = [
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 05:46:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 05:21:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 06:31:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 06:46:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 07:34:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 07:55:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 08:46:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 09:16:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 09:46:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 10:36:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 11:47:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 11:55:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 12:37:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 14:27:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 14:37:33" },
    ];
// And I have time periods, for ex:
var time = ["05:45 - 06:00", "06:00 - 07:00",
     "07:00 - 08:00", "08:00 - 09:00", "09:00 - 10:00",
     "10:00 - 11:00", "11:00 - 12:00", "12:00 - 13:00",
     "13:00 - 14:00", "14:00 - 14:45"];

var formatedTime = time.map(function(val) {
    return val.split(" - ");
});

var grouped = formatedTime.reduce((groups, currentValue, cI) => {
    let min = parseInt(currentValue[0].substring(0,2));
    let max = parseInt(currentValue[1].substring(0,2));
    let filtered = array.filter(val => {
        let validDate = val.dateTime.replace(/\//g,'-').replace(' ','T').replace('19','2019');
        let date = new Date(validDate).getHours();
        let result = false;
        if(date >= min && date < max) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
    

    let date = currentValue[0] + " - " + currentValue[1];
    groups.push({
        time: date,
        groupedData: filtered
    });
    return groups;

}, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

So as u can see at array I have data for **time 14:00 - 14:45** after filtering data does not appear correctly.

In my array i have two reccords:

```
{ item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 14:27:33" },
{ item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 14:37:33" },
```

I try to found sollution, but i stuck.

Expected output:

```
{
    "time": "14:00 - 14:45",
    "groupedData": [{ item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 14:27:33" },
    { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 14:37:33" }]

 }
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @MaheerAli i eddt question

Comment: You're only comparing hours, but should be comparing minutes too.

Comment: I think you asked this question few days back. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56269154/jquery-how-to-filter-two-dates-and-time-from-dictionary-and-group-at-new-array/56270625#56270625

Comment: @MuraliNepalli nope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compare the time directly and find first the group and then the item in the result set.

```js
var array = [{ item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 05:46:33" }, { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 05:21:33" }, { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 06:31:33" }, { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 06:46:33" }, { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 07:34:33" }, { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 07:55:33" }, { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 08:46:33" }, { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 09:16:33" }, { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 09:46:33" }, { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 10:36:33" }, { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 11:47:33" }, { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 11:55:33" }, { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 12:37:33" }, { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 14:27:33" }, { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 14:37:33" }],
    time = ["05:45 - 06:00", "06:00 - 07:00", "07:00 - 08:00", "08:00 - 09:00", "09:00 - 10:00", "10:00 - 11:00", "11:00 - 12:00", "12:00 - 13:00", "13:00 - 14:00", "14:00 - 14:45"],
    result = array.reduce((r, o) => {
        var part = o.dateTime.slice(9, 14),
            group = time.find(t => {
                var [min, max] = t.split(' - ');
                return min <= part && part < max;
            }),
            temp = r.find(({ time }) => time === group);

        if (!group) return r;
        if (!temp) {
            r.push({ time: group, groupedData: [o] });
            return r;
        }
        temp.groupedData.push(o);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you're only comparing the hours and ignoring the minutes. This causes the issue you have with the `14:00 - 14:45` period.

Because of how the dates are formatted and how you perform the comparison, you can just get away with a string-based comparison here:

```js
const array = [
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 05:46:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 05:21:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 06:31:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 06:46:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 07:34:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 07:55:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 08:46:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 09:16:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 09:46:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 10:36:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 11:47:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 11:55:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 12:37:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 14:27:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 14:37:33" },
    ];

const times = ["05:45 - 06:00", "06:00 - 07:00",
     "07:00 - 08:00", "08:00 - 09:00", "09:00 - 10:00",
     "10:00 - 11:00", "11:00 - 12:00", "12:00 - 13:00",
     "13:00 - 14:00", "14:00 - 14:45"];

const grouped = times.map(time => {
  const [min, max] = time.split(' - ');
  const groupedData = array.filter(({dateTime}) => {
    const ts = dateTime.substring(9, 14);
    
    return ts >= min && ts < max;
  });
  
  return {time, groupedData};
});

console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const array = [
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 05:46:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 05:21:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 06:31:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 06:46:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 07:34:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 07:55:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 08:46:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 09:16:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 09:46:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 10:36:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 11:47:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 11:55:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 12:37:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 14:27:33" },
        { item: "item", category: "category", dateTime: "19/05/23 14:37:33" },
    ];
    // And I have time periods, for ex:
    const times = ["05:45 - 06:00", "06:00 - 07:00",
        "07:00 - 08:00", "08:00 - 09:00", "09:00 - 10:00",
        "10:00 - 11:00", "11:00 - 12:00", "12:00 - 13:00",
        "13:00 - 14:00", "14:00 - 14:45"
    ];

    const result = [];

    times.forEach((time) => {

        const [min, max] = time.split(" - ");

        const groupedData = array.filter(({ dateTime }) => {
            return `${min}:00`.localeCompare(dateTime.slice(-8)) <= 0 && `${max}:00`.localeCompare(dateTime.slice(-8)) >= 0;
        })

        result.push({
            time,
            groupedData
        });
    });


    console.log('@>result', result)
```